# Magento 2 after customer login redirect to my orders failed to set login_redirect session

Tags: magento2, login, redirect, cookie, customer-session

Steps to produce :

1. Login to customer
2. click on my order link

This redirects to login page again(Session not able to handle login)

> This happens only on **FIREFOX** browser.

I need proper solution which can be solved by programatically.

> **Note** : I have tried to set "network.http.response.timeout" and it's working but I can not tell each customer to do so.